# How do I implement Quartz.Net to schedule tasks for my MVC3 web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building a project to send messages to users. The client wants a way to schedule these messages to be sent out at a certain time, for example, he creates the message at 2am but wants it to be sent out at 10am without his intervention, where do I begin with this sort of thing? I'm using ASP.NET MVC3, any help is appreciated.

*Update*

Darin has suggested Quartz.net, I've finally gotten around to attempting to set it up. But I'm not really understanding how to implement it with my web app.

I'm assuming I should be able to make an httprequest from my service to an action on my webapp, triggered by quartz. But I'm not sure how to communicate between the webapp and this service, such as sending instructions to the quartz server.

So far, I've created a windows service, set up the installers, and added the Quartz.net server 2010 solution to my service project, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 4):

Using a [managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx) with [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) or a console application which you would schedule with the Windows task scheduler seems like a good approaches to achieve that.

Comment: Quartz.NET is a great product that I've utilized in several products.  It is dependable and scalable.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I'll look into these.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, there are scheduled tasks... either make a localhost request at a specific time, or write an executable/service to be called.

A possible alternative if you can't use scheduled tasks (but may be dependent upon the website being available to the Internet) is to make a remote request-maker program or use a website monitoring service. Have either of those make a request to a particular page/querystring on your site periodically. Then, make the web application perform a particular task (send an email) whenever that resource is requested.

A few free monitoring services are limited to one request every hour or half-hour, or you can pay to have it checked more often. The resource's code could be made to record the message-sending event, (thus making them only get sent once, regardless of how often the request is made)